# Tile server for other map data than OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, openstreetmap, satellite-image

Within my Android application I display some data within a map. To do that I currently download some map data from an OpenStreetMap tile server and store it locally (so that users can access an already used map without causing traffic again).

Now I have seen some Android apps using other map data/sattelite pictures (perhaps from Google?). Unfortunately I could not find any tile servers that offer the same principle like OSM where it is possible to cache the map tiles locally. So does anybody know of similar projects/tile servers that are not OSM but provide the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elmi...

I didn't use tiles images of map for google..

But I have one sample link which provide tile image from google

[Tile Image of Google Map](http://mt3.google.com/vt/v=w2.97&x=1433&y=897&z=11)

Comment: That's cool - thanks! Any ideas where to get satellite tiles from?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe on MapQuest : http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map
Aerial view and others

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody has the same problems: there exists some Android code at http://sourceforge.net/projects/libwlocate/ which already uses OpenStreetMap, Google Map and Google Sattelite view optionally for drawing Maps.